# Send a user defined String within the SDP packet

Tags: sip, asterisk, sdp

is there a way to send a short user defined string from the Caller to the Callee within the SDP part of an INVITE message (in a manner like steganography)? I tried to set the string with a length of approximately 15, in the **k=**, **p=**, **e=**, **u=** field. However the Asterisk server does not accept the Invite message. For sure, I set the new length in the IP-Header and UDP-Header furthermore I calculated the new Internet checksum of the IP-Header. As well I considered the CRLF scheme and the order of the fields.

Goal is, to transport data within the SDP data from the Caller to the Callee and vice versa, when the Callee responds with the 200 OK message to the Caller.

Thank you in advance!

**Message with i=111.111.111.111 which is not accepted by the Asterisk:**

```
INVITE sip:1000@192.168.0.14 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.11.2:6060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKGvBkM0qF4
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1000@192.168.0.14>
From: <sip:2000@192.168.0.14>;tag=SOXFP4ir
Call-ID: BEkXWRwn-1318101970419@x61.local
CSeq: 39 INVITE
Content-Length: 231
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:2000@192.168.11.2:6060;transport=UDP>

v=0
o=user1 1396633799 2096570444 IN IP4 192.168.11.2
s=-
i=111.111.111.111
c=IN IP4 192.168.11.2
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
```

**Same Message but without i=111.111.111.111. This packet is accepted and the call proceeding ends successfully (with TRYING, RING 200OK)**

```
INVITE sip:1000@192.168.0.14 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.11.2:6060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKESGSZD1V6
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:1000@192.168.0.14>
From: <sip:2000@192.168.0.14>;tag=YPPrCWLp
Call-ID: 10MpKHYD-1318102031971@x61.local
CSeq: 41 INVITE
Content-Length: 211
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:2000@192.168.11.2:6060;transport=UDP>

v=0
o=user1 1682420165 643979666 IN IP4 192.168.11.2
s=-
c=IN IP4 192.168.11.2
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
```

Actually everything looks fine. And I can not see the response. I am intercepting the packets over iptables with NFQUEUE. Then just a few strstr, memcpy etc. to alter and build the new packets. I know there are some SDP stacks/APIs but in my case the quick and dirty solution is sufficient.

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try the i= field. As stated in RFC 4566:

> The "i=" field is intended to provide a free-form human-readable description of the session or the purpose of a media stream.  It is not suitable for parsing by automata.

So the Asterisk server shouldn't validate that field, enabling you to put the text you want there.

Comment: Yes tried it a few minutes ago without success... As in the other cases, the INVITE packet leaves the pc with the softphone, is received by the Asterisk server. Here wireshark shows me everything is fine. But thats it.

Comment: Until now, I am not really sure how to debug this kind of error. In Asterisk CLI I tried the command "sip set debug on". But it does not show me any useful information. Do you know how to set appropriate debug information?

Comment: In addition, is there any setting or limitation of the asterisk server which prohibits this kind of information? Furthermore I am not really sure if the i= message is handed over unchanged to the Callee, sadly I have no idea how to test this behaviour. I have just a simple linux softphone and a Siemens S685IP.

Comment: Quite interesting... set the "core set debug" and "core set verbose" to 1, 9 and 999 etc.. If I send a packet with the i= no verbose/debug output is produced. However the packet reaches the asterisk server (seen in wireshark on asterisk server). If I use a packet without the i= field everything is shown in the debug/verbose messages.

Comment: How do you add the field? Can you edit your question and paste the packet you send to the server? Maybe there is something wrong with it that the server doesn't like. Also, there should be answer to your INVITE. Can you see it with Wireshark?